# Would it be on topic to request a review of a stackoverflow answer I gave?

Tags: discussion

A stackoverflow answer I gave prompted a downvote from the very beginning plus snide remarks about my skills and so forth.

The downvote I can handle, the snide remarks are unfair in my opinion, but it is really one-on-one there. I do not have Spring skills but my intuition and the fact that the OP accepted my answer tells me that my assumptions and suggestions are actually OK.

Would it be on topic if I post a link to the answer in question and have people skilled in Spring and jQuery look to see if my assumptions and suggestions are as poor as this guy insists on telling me? it would be lovely to be vindicated and if the opposite happens, I would delete the answer instead.

If on topic, I will add the link here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> the fact that the OP accepted my answer tells me that my assumptions and suggestions are actually OK

Accepted answer usually means that your answer worked for the OP. It doesn't necessarily mean your answer is a good practice or that it's bug-free. Don't forget the the OP most likely knows less than you.

> Would it be on topic if I post a link to the answer in question

Almost. Just posting the link is not enough, you have to actually include the code, per the [FAQ](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/faq).

But otherwise, I think posting your code here would be okay.

Comment: "OP knows less than you": Yes, hence my wish to make sure it is correct/not violating best practice...

Comment: @mplungjan if the code runs and you think it does what it should, it is on topic for code review if you post it directly in the question. Feel free to go ahead.

Comment: Typo alert: It doesn't necessarily mean your **answer** is a good...

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Actually, I think I actually need that people from here visits the question at SO. the answer is too short to be posted here and the end result would stay here and not make any difference there... Thanks for the clarification. I will consider it for a larger answer...